# Asp.Net MVC 2 - Changing the PropertyValueRequired string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

Using a resx file in the App_GlobalResources directory, I've been able to change the default message for the PropertyValueInvalid string of the model validators.

But it doesn't work to translate the message when a value is required (PropertyValueRequired.)

In the Global.asax.cs Application_Start() I've changed the resource class key, like this:

```
DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "Messages";
```

And in the Messages.resx files I've put two entries:

- "PropertyValueInvalid" => "O valor '{0}' é inválido para o campo {1}."
- "PropertyValueRequired" = > "É necessário digitar o {0}."

Thanks.

Comment: I've noticed the same behaviour. Solution anyone?

Comment: @mare What is your exact problem - PropertyValueRequired message is not being used from resx file in modal validation using data annotation?

Comment: Yes, exactly as daniel's issue.

Comment: have u tried my below solution?

Comment: I think Darin's is a bit better , it's an upgrade of your solution.

Answer (score 17):

RequiredAttribute not used DefaultModelBinder.GetValueRequiredResource.
Create custom DataAnnotationsModelValidator class.

```
public class MyRequiredAttributeAdapter : RequiredAttributeAdapter
{
  public MyRequiredAttributeAdapter(ModelMetadata metadata, 
                                    ControllerContext context, 
                                    RequiredAttribute attribute) 
         : base(metadata, context, attribute)
  {
    attribute.ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Messages);
    attribute.ErrorMessageResourceName = "PropertyValueRequired";
  }
}
```

and register adapter in Global.asax.

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(
    typeof(RequiredAttribute), 
    typeof(MyRequiredAttributeAdapter));
```

Hope this help!

[Reusable Validation Error Message Resource Strings for DataAnnotations](http://ryanrivest.com/blog/archive/2010/01/15/reusable-validation-error-message-resource-strings-for-dataannotations.aspx)

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I have been looking for, thanks! (ps: the link is broken)

Comment: this is the best answer i've found on this subject

Comment: This is great. Please also see this for a solution to a trouble you might run into
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16211476/268091

Comment: Where is a good best practice place to store the DataAnnotationsModelValidator class?

Comment: also what namespaces (using) does this require?

Comment: It can't find messages. I have added references to using System.Web.Mvc; & using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

Comment: @niico Messages class in the line attribute.ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Messages); is the name of the resourcefile!

Comment: Link is down now, can anyone help?

Answer (score 9):

This message is baked into `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` assembly under the key `RequiredAttribute_ValidationError`. You could write a custom validation attribute:

```
public class MyRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public MyRequiredAttribute()
    {
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Messages);
        ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required";
    }
}
```

and then inside your `Messages.resx` file define the `Required` string:

```
Required => É necessário digitar o {0}.
```

and finally decorate your view model property with this custom attribute:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [MyRequired]
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So for the same concept the ASP.NET MVC team is using two different constructs?

Comment: @mare, we can only hope that this will be fixed/made easier in future versions of MVC.

Comment: For this to work on client-side in ASP.NET MVC 3 you will need to either register the custom attribute (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5954452/169) or use AttributeAdapter approach (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5207912/169).

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
[Required (ErrorMessageResourceName="Required",ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(Messages)]

public string Foo { get; set; }

Required => É necessário digitar o {0}.
```

Or

```
Required => {0} field is required.
```

Please refer below link for complete asp.net mvc localisation guide
[asp.net mvc localisation guide](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html)

Comment: how to make it global so it doesn't need to add (ErrorMessageResourceName="Required",ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(Messages).    or how to make error message for the field needed a integer value but user enters 'abc'

Comment: not sure what you mean by - make it global but for integer value error message - Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522369/how-use-data-annotations-for-verifying-input-particular-type

Answer (score 0):

Just add like this

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Your Error Message, here..!")]
```