# How use data annotations for verifying input particular type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

User must input in form only integers. How use data annotations for verifying ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this out:

```
[Range(0, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage="Invalid Number")]
public int? Number { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Data Annotations Extensions](https://dataannotationsextensions.apphb.com/) which includes an `Integer` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [Numeric] data annotation for that. If you're dealing with money there is also [DataType(DataType.Currency)]

Edit: Numeric is actually part of [Data Annotations Extensions](http://dataannotationsextensions.org/Numeric/Create)

Comment: Where is that attribute defined? DataAnnotationsExtensions?

Comment: Actually, it's part of Data Annotations extension. I had forgotten I'd forgotten I was using it.

Comment: And how with int? Show me please

Comment: This is for when you're taking a string as an input but need it to be numeric such as a SSN. A property of type int should automatically be validated as a number.

Comment: I have property Price. And user musst input there only integers(int)