# Validation of List<int> property

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-validation

I am using datannotations and the server/client side validation stuff in ASP.NET MVC 2. Everything works fine if a class has properties such as:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "whatever")]
String blah;
```

but I have no idea how to make this:

```
[Range(13134, 42352345, ErrorMessage = "outside of range")]
List<int> blah;
```

where I want the int to be in that range.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-validation There are several examples at this tag. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383669/how-to-create-custom-validation-attribute-for-mvc like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to write a custom validator to do this.  [This article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx) by Scott Gu is useful for explaining writing custom validators

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvccustomvalidation_topic2) msdn article may be more appropriate as it specifically discusses custom range validation