# How can I turn a JSON into a C# Dictionary?

Tags: c#, javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3, dictionary

I have the following JSON:

```
validate = {
    '(\\.org|\\.info|\\.biz|\\.name)$': [
        { 'type': 'size', 'pattern': /^.{3,64}$/, 'error': 'Your domain can have at max 26 characters and at least 3.' }
    ],
    '.*': [
        { 'type': 'general', 'pattern': /^[^\.-].*[^\.-]$/, 'message': 'Your domain name shouldn\'t contain . or - at the beginning or the end.' },
        { 'type': 'characters', 'pattern': /^[abcdefghijklmnopqrstwuvxyz0123456789]+$/, 'error': 'Your domain can have at max 26 characters and at least 3.' }
    ]
};
```

and tried to use like this:

```
var validate = new Dictionary<string, dynamic> {
    {
        @"(\.org|\.info|\.biz|\.name)$",
        new {
            Type = "size",
            Pattern = @"^.{3,64}$",
            Message = "Your domain can have at max 26 characters and at least 3."
        }
    }
};
```

Where the key of the dynamic object its the regex pattern for the domain extension and the regex inside `Pattern` key its the one that should match the domain name.

But I can't figure out how I put 2 validations type inside the `dynamic` part of the `Dictionary`.

Has anyone did anything like it before or it's stupid and I should do in another way?

The point of doing it this way it's that I can serialize the dictionary as a Json.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to create a custom data annotation with it and afterwards I wanna send that content from the dictionary as a Json to the view using asp-net-mvc3 so I can have the validation rules on the C# code and everytime we change the C# validation, the client side will follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with a `List<dynamic>` at the dynamic part of my Dictionary:

```
var validate = new Dictionary<string, List<dynamic>> {
    {
        "(\\.org|\\.info|\\.biz|\\.name)$",
        new List<dynamic>
        {
            new {
                Type = "size",
                Pattern = @"^.{3,64}$",
                Message = "Your domain can have at max 26 characters and at least 3."
            }
        }
    },
    {
        ".*",
        new List<dynamic>
        {
            new {
                Type = "general",
                Pattern = @"^[^\.-].*[^\.-]$",
                Message = "Your domain name shouldn\'t contain . or - at the beginning or the end."
            },
            new {
                Type = "characters",
                Pattern = @"^[abcdefghijklmnopqrstwuvxyz0123456789]+$",
                Message = "Your domain name should contain only alphanumeric characters."
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And using `Json` from `JsonResult` mvc3 view it returned the json I needed.

Comment: You can also do Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>

Comment: That would been a great solution too.

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to do this for an MVC site I think you should look into [custom validation](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx), and let the runtime handle the plumbing for you.  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383669/how-to-create-custom-validation-attribute-for-mvc) which discusses how to implement a custom RegularExpressionAttribute, which seems here.

Comment: I'm pretty sharp at custom validation, specially if it is mvc3, regardless your link its from mvc2 I don't think they have too much diference. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2383669/840901) question can't solve my problem when it comes to send that regex validation as a serialized Json to the view.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to validate a regex, no?

Comment: I'm trying to validate using regex, but I need inside a dictionary because I want to iterate it after.