# asp.net mvc [EmailAddress] does not work for missing suffix

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using `[EmailAddress]` attribute to validate my email input textfield as the following

```
[EmailAddress]
public string NewBusNotificationEmail { get; set; }
```

For my testing, I tried the following

`test` - validation failed

`test@` - validation failed

`test@test.` - validation failed

However, when I tried `test@test` - validation passed

I also noticed that it does not test for madeup suffix like `tets@test.test` - validation passed. For `test@test`, it should be validation fail. Why not? how to fix this?

Comment: I am getting error for this input `test@test`. I am not getting any error for `test@test.test` and it is acceptable because you cannot validate `ALL` domains using `regex`. By the way, `EmailAddress` attribute validates email string using a regex.

Comment: Just now I tested and it is working as expected, i mean showing validation error for `test@test` on both client side and server side (`Model.IsValid`). And as I mentioned in above comment `test@test.test` is a valid input based on regex. Let me know if you have more questions.

Answer (score 0):

if you want limited to some domain you can use `Regex` .

like this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid e-mail adress")]
```

or you can create an CustomeAttribute and add some `Black List | White List` for some domain.
this is an example for custome attribute ,

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple  = false)]
public class EmailAddressAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    private const string pattern = @"^\w+([-+.]*[\w-]+)*@(\w+([-.]?\w+)){1,}\.\w{2,4}$";

static EmailAddressAttribute()
{
    // necessary to enable client side validation
    DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(EmailAddressAttribute), typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter));
}

public EmailAddressAttribute() : base(pattern)
{
}
}
```

Reference :[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383669/how-to-create-custom-validation-attribute-for-mvc)